# Need to modify json and return inside aync find operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I need to go through a list of object ids, find a user, and then modify the json object and return it.

I've looked into bluebird but the code below doesn't execute how I would like it. It seems as though modifying the json object is done after returning it.

I've tried to return `user["test"] = "lol"` but that only returns the value of "test" whereas I need the entire updated json.

```
Promise.map(['5781635026d6fad4486d81e9', '578296e31029e27b4ea53e9d'], function(i) {
  return User.findOneAsync({
    _id: i
  }).then(function(user) {
    user["test"] = "lol";
    return user;
  });
}).then(function(array) {
  res.send(array);
})
```

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Please show the content of `array` and `user`. In code you have shown the the `array` would be an Array containing the returned `user` objects. Beside that JSON is a string, you are talking about JavaScript object.

Comment: the array just contains the user objects without the modifications.

Comment: What is the content of `user` after `user["test"] = "lol";`? Place a  `console.dir(user);` directly after `user["test"] = "lol";`.

Comment: it is the same user object without the "test" property.

Comment: What does `console.dir(Object.isFrozen(user));` and `console.dir(Object.isExtensible(user));` show you?

Comment: isFrozen shows: `false false` and isExtensible shows: `true true`

Comment: That does not really make sense because this simplified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uy289cu/) it works fine. And if the Object is not frozen  and extensible then it should be possible to add new properties. Probably it is something related to mongoose. But I can't help you further because  I never really used mongodb.

Comment: @t.niese yes..it doesn't make sense at all. Also i'm not sure how you got your fiddle working because it doesn't have access to a mongodb

Comment: I just replaced `return User.findOneAsync` with `return Promise.resolve( _id: i })`, as a _fake_ request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple approach you could take is to use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator with the array of ids in your query, then apply the **[`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)** method to return plain JS objects as [Mongoose documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js) do not allow adding of properties.

Check out this example:

```
User.find({ "_id": { "$in": ['5781635026d6fad4486d81e9', '578296e31029e27b4ea53e9d'] } })
    .lean()
    .exec()
    .then(function(docs) {  
        var users = docs.map(function(user) {
            user["test"] = "lol";
            return user;
        });
        res.send(users);
    })
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know how the object are protected? And why they return `true` for `Object.isExtensible(user)`?

Comment: @t.niese Not really sure but because Mongoose documents are instances of the Mongoose Model and thus they do not allow adding of properties